# Proving that the sign of the sum of this alternating sequence depends on the sign of the largest number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation

> 1. Listing the powers of 2 in order, i.e, "1, 2, 4, 8, 16,..."
> 2. Then alternate their signs and add them. For example: -1 + 2 -4 + 8... or 1 - 2 + 4 - 8....
>
> Prove that the sum will be positive if the last term is positive, and vice versa.

I thought of this problem looking at another problem (which involved expressing numbers as the alternating sequence of powers of 2). So while I was playing around with the first problem, I realized that the sum is positive if the last term is positive, and it is negative if the last term is negative. Intuitively the answer is obvious: the last term has the highest magnitude. But I want to prove it. Unfortunately I am uneducated in number theory (or whatever part of mathematics this problem belongs to). And so I have no ideas on the problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try and do this by induction.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could try finding closed formula's for $1+2^2+\cdots+2^{2k}$ and $2+2^3+\cdots+2^{2k+1}$ and subtract them

Comment: Yes, the last term has the highest magnitude; but this in itself is not enough. However, it _is_ enough to show that the magnitude of the last term is greater than the sum of all the previous magnitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$E(k)=1+2^2+\cdots+2^{2k}=\frac{(2^2)^{k+1}-1}{2^2-1}$$ by geometric series on $2^2$. We also have $$O(k)=2+2^3+\cdots+2^{2k+1}=2\cdot E(k)$$
It is clear that, if we look at $1-2+4-\cdots+(-2)^a$, that, when $a$ is odd, we get, for some $k$: $$E(k)-O(k)=E(k)-2E(k)=-E(k)<0$$
and if $a$ is even, then we get \begin{align}
E(k)-O(k-1)&=E(k)-(O(k)-2^{2k+1})\\
&=-E(k)+2^{2k+1}\\
&=-\frac{(2^2)^{k+1}-1}{2^2-1}+2^{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{1-2^{2k+2}+2^{2k+3}-2^{2k+1}}{2^2-1}\\
&=\frac{1-2^{2k+2}+2\cdot 2^{2k+2}-2^{2k+1}}{2^2-1}\\
&=\frac{1+2^{2k+2}-2^{2k+1}}{2^2-1}\\
&=\frac{1+ 2\cdot 2^{2k+1}-2^{2k+1}}{2^2-1}\\
&=\frac{1+2^{2k+1}}{2^2-1}\\
&>0
\end{align}
Which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ be any strictly increasing sequence of positive numbers (for instance, $a_n=2^{n-1}$ as in your example).
If $n=2m>0$ is even, then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k = \sum_{k=1}^m((-1)^{2k-1}a_{2k-1}+(-1)^{2k}a_{2k})= \sum_{k=1}^k\underbrace{(a_{2k}-a_{2k-1})}_{>0}>0$$
The corresponding claim for odd $n$ requires slightly more work.
Define $s_m =\sum_{k=1}^{2m} (-1)^ka_k$. Then 
$$\tag1s_{m+1}=s_{m}-a_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2} $$
and we can show by induction on $m$ that
$$\tag20<s_{m}<a_{2m} $$
for all $m\ge 1$. Indeed, $s_1=-a_1+a_2$ is $>0$ because $a_2>a_1$ and is $<a_2$ because $a_1>0$.
Assume $(2)$ holds for $m$, then using $(1)$ we find
$$s_{m+1}=s_m-a_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}<\underbrace{a_{1m}-a_{2m+1}}_{<0}+a_{2m+2}$$
and $$ s_{m+1}=s_m-a_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}>-a_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}>0,$$
as desired.
From $s_m>0$ we (re-)gain our result for even $n=2m$, 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k=s_m>0,$$
whereas for odd $n=2m+1>1$ we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k=s_m-a_{2m+1}<a_{2m}-a_{2m+1}<0.$$